# turning off case sensitivity in r

Tags: r, case-sensitive

I am having difficulty with case sensitivity. Can we turn it off?

```
A1 <- c("a", "A", "a", "a", "A", "A", "a")
B1 <- c(rep("a", length(A1)))

A1 == B1
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

should be all `TRUE`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's no way to turn off case sensitivity of `==`, but coercing both character vectors to uppercase and *then* testing for equality amounts to the same thing:

```
toupper(A1)
[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"

toupper(A1)==toupper(B1)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 32):

As Josh O'Brien said. To extend a bit on caseless matching in R, that is actually possible with regular expressions (using eg `grep` and `grepl`)

In this case you could use `mapply` and `grepl` like this, provided you're matching single characters :

```
A1 <- c("a", "A", "a", "a", "A", "A", "a")
B1 <- c(rep("a", length(A1)))

mapply(grepl,A1,B1,ignore.case=TRUE)
#    a    A    a    a    A    A    a 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

You have to be careful though, because it also matches partial strings like this :

```
C1 <- rep('ab',length(A1))
mapply(grepl,A1,C1,ignore.case=TRUE)
#    a    A    a    a    A    A    a 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

This may or may not be what you want.

On a sidenote, if you match with regular expressions and you want to ignore the case, you can also use the construct `(?i)` to turn on caseless matching and `(?-i)` to turn off caseless matching :

```
D1 <- c('abc','aBc','Abc','ABc','aBC')

grepl('a(?i)bc',D1) # caseless matching on B and C
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

grepl('a(?i)b(?-i)c',D1) # caseless matching only on B
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: +1 That's a fun and informative addition.  If you want to use `grepl` and _not_ accept substring matches, I suppose you could do `mapply(grepl,A1,C1,ignore.case=TRUE) & mapply(grepl,C1, A1,ignore.case=TRUE)`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien : You could indeed, but that construct is rather unlikely to excel in efficiency... ;-)

Comment: Yup. And in whatever the opposite of code golf is, it's a contender!

Comment: I almost always compare with grepl for things like this, much easier to read, manipulate and understand. Slower than == though :/

Comment: A slight alternative might be: mapply(grepl, tolower(A1), tolower(B1), fixed = TRUE)