# r %in% operator | control case sensitivity

Tags: r, operators, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Is there a way to control the case sensitivity of the %in% operator? In my case I want it to return true no matter the case of the input:

```
stringList <- c("hello", "world")
"Hello" %in% stringList
"helLo" %in% stringList
"hello" %in% stringList
```

Consider this code as a reproducible example, however in my real application I am also using a list of strings on the left and check for the presence of words from stringList.

Comment: Also, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361589/turning-off-case-sensitivity-in-r) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085620/which-command-in-r-with-case-insensitive).

Comment: Hmm I cannot see why this is a duplicate, however the posts you linked contain potential workarounds.

Comment: It is not 100% duplicated as we are using `%in%` while linked post are using different functions, but check the answers, they are using the same "grepl with ignore case" and `tolower` or `toupper` functions to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: yes, but I would like to continue using %in%, maybe someone as a good solution for that..currently i think about converting both sides to lower/upper case

Answer (score 4):

Use `grepl` instead as it has an `ignore.case` parameter:

```
grepl("^HeLLo$",stringList,ignore.case=TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

The first argument is a regular expression, so it gives you more flexibility, but you have to start with `^` and end with `$` to avoid picking up sub-strings.

Comment: Thank you James,
what if the input on the left is also a list of strings?

Comment: @florian You can use the or operator for regex, `|`. But it depends on how you want to handle multiple strings.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @James's answer, you can also use `tolower` if you want to avoid regexes:

```
tolower("HeLLo") %in% stringlist
```

---

If left side is also a character vector then we make tolower both sides, e.g.:

```
x <- c("Hello", "helLo", "hello", "below")
stringList <- c("heLlo", "world")
tolower(x) %in% tolower(stringList)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: But what if `"Hello"` in `stringList` ?

Comment: That is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: hmm thank you I will consider using tolower on both sides